Is there any way to get date and time without using internet and not from the Windows os?
We are creating an application with license which doesn't use internet we use a key to provide the license for particular period of time. But the problem is when the time is changed in the user's system is also affects the license as well. Like when we have a license for month 6th and when the date is changed to 6th month the license works but that shouldn't.
I tried to access date and time from BIOS but C# can't access the data from BIOS as far I know. I'm expecting to get the date from BIOS or any other way to resolve the license problem

Do not add unrelated tags to your question. This is not about WPF, nor is it about Windows Forms (both of which are UI technologies). A GPS module could give you time, but that would require the user to make a GPS device available to you, which seems incredibly impractical. Other than that, no, there won't really be a way to get the date and time. Your idea of using the BIOS date and time is a bit odd too, since nothing would stop someone from manually changing that either.

In the end, the solution is to simply forget it.

Either require access to a time server or switch to a licensing model that does not depend on time.

And even then, the chances you'd make an external check to a time server that isn't crackable is unlikely. I've had people hack my code, replace the URL being called and spoof a response. Licencing is hard. The best approach is to push some critical processing to your website effectively making the app useless as a standalone.

You cannot do that. If you dont have internet or someone else with internet connected, time can always be cheated.
Consider changing your model to something you can track yourself in your application. Instead of 6 months offer them 200 Hours. Now keep track of the time your application is running in an encypted file they cant edit, and once you exceed 200 hours lock it up.

Also: if you don't charge millions by the minute, the effort is probably not worth the theoretical losses.

You have a few options on how you can try and get around this (assuming that your machine cannot access the internet and doesn't have a GPS module).
You can use a separate 'Licence server' (your own developed or 3PP).  This runs on another server on the network.
You then set a requirement that this server must be connected to the internet.  This normally allows you to get around security restrictions which means your primary server/machine must not have internet access.
You then call an API from the program to determine if the licence is valid or not and the licence server does what it needs to do.
If that also cannot have Internet access, then you could try simply comparing date & time between the other server and your machine running the application.  If they are more than say 30 seconds out of sync, then you raise a licence exception.
Although it is unlikely that both machines have the same date & time changed at the same time, this is still possible.  So it only deters the average user, not the determined.
But probably the simplest option is simply to store the date & time in your application at time of launch (preferably in an obfuscated and encrypted manner).  And if you notice that the current date & time is prior to the last stored then you raise a licence exception and stop the application running.

but my base problem when i use expired license in another pc within the range of license days which doesn't connected to any server . Some software use particular methods to do this even it is connected to new fresh PCs without internet nor server . If you know any method regarding this you can share with me and thank you for the above suggestion.
